# Only One form working at a time in react

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I have 2 sets of forms:One is for login and the other one is for user registration.Both of them have their own components,css files and routes.But surprisingly,at any given point of time,only the login form works even though the code is the same.I even removed the form tag still my submitted content is not shown.I have also tried to try p

Here is the code for the 2 files.

```
 //Registeration.js
    import React from 'react'
    import './registeration_form.css'
    class Register extends React.Component
    {
      constructor(props)
      {
        super(props);
        this.state={username:'',email:'',password:'',confirm_pass:''}
        this.change_email=this.change_email.bind(this)
        this.change_password=this.change_password.bind(this)
        this.change_username=this.change_username.bind(this)
        this.confirm_pasword=this.confirm_pasword.bind(this)
        this.valdiate_data=this.valdiate_data.bind(this)
      }

      change_username(e)
      {
        this.setState({username:e.target.value})
      }

      change_email(e)
      {
        this.setState({email:e.target.value})
      }

      change_password(e)
      {
        this.setState({password:e.target.value})
      }

      confirm_pasword(e)
      {
        this.setState({confirm_pass:e.target.value})

      }

      valdiate_data(event)
      {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log("hello")
        console.log(this.state.username)
        console.log(this.state.email)
        console.log(this.state.password)
        console.log(this.state.confirm_pass)
      }

      render()
      {
        return(
          <div>
            <div id="register">
              <form method="post">
                <legend id="register_legend"><b>Registeration Form</b></legend>
                <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" onChange={this.change_username} placeholder="Username"/>
                <label htmlFor ="email">Email Id:</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="Email" onChange={this.change_email} placeholder="Email Id"/>
                <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" onChange={this.change_password} placeholder="Password"/>
                <label htmlFor ="confirm password">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type ="text" id="confirm_password" name="Confirm password" onChange={this.confirm_pasword} placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Register" onClick={this.validate_data}/>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    export default Register
     //Login.js`enter code here`
     import React from 'react'
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
    import Supers from 'superagent'
    import './Login_Page.css'
    //import defaults from 'superagent-defaults'

    //var defaults_arg=require('superagent-defaults');

    //var superagent_arguments=defaults_arg();
    //var superagent_default_arg = defaults()

    class Login extends React.Component
    {
      constructor(props)
      {
        super(props);
        this.state={username:'',password:'',API_Data:[]}
        this.Login_data_password=this.Login_data_password.bind(this)
        this.Login_data_username=this.Login_data_username.bind(this)
        this.MainRedirect=this.MainRedirect.bind(this)
        this.api_call_login=this.api_call_login.bind(this)
      }

    Login_data_username(e)
    {
      this.setState({username:e.target.value})
    }

    Login_data_password(password)
    {
      this.setState({password:password.target.value})
    }

    MainRedirect()
    {
      window.location = '/main';
    }

    api_call_login(e)
    {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log(this.state.password,this.state.username)
      Supers.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_ops/user_login/')
      .send({'username':this.state.username,'password':this.state.password})
      .end((error, response) =>
      {
        if(!error && response)
        {
            console.log(JSON.parse(response.body))
            console.log('Object')
            console.log(Object.keys(JSON.parse(response.body)))
            this.setState({API_Data:JSON.parse(response.body)})
            if(this.state.API_Data['Successful_Login']==='True')
            {
              this.setState({'username':'','password':''})
              console.log('Switching')

              //superagent_arguments
              //.set('Authorization',this.state.API_Data['token'])
              //.set('Content-Type','application/json')

              //console.log(superagent_arguments)

              this.MainRedirect()
            }
            else
            {
                this.setState({'username':'','password':''})
                window.location='/login'
            }
          }
        });
      }

      render(){
        return(
            <div>
              <div id="container">
                <form method="POST">
                  <legend id= "login_legend"><b>Login Form</b></legend>
                  <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
                  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" onChange={this.Login_data_username} placeholder="Username"/>
                  <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" onChange={this.Login_data_password} placeholder="Password"/>
                  <input type="submit" value="Login" onClick={this.api_call_login}/>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
      )
      }
      }

    export default Login
```

Comment: Can you be more specific and elaborate? This is not understandable.

Comment: Ok.So i am creating a website where there is a landing page.On that there are 2 buttons-login and register.They respectively use the code written in their separate files and i have created forms to take data from the user and send via an api.The problem is that the login form works properly but the registration form does not work even thought the code is correct.

Comment: Do you get any errors? If not, try using a `debugger` inside the `onClick` method of the register button. And also paste the code for your landing page.

Answer (score 1):

You're using input tags with the same id in both components and because id can be used only for one element, HTML recognize only the latest element with that id.

Now take a look at your code:

```
// Register.js

<label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" onChange={this.change_username} placeholder="Username"/>
<label htmlFor ="email">Email Id:</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="Email" onChange={this.change_email} placeholder="Email Id"/>
<label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" onChange={this.change_password} placeholder="Password"/>

// Login.js

<label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" onChange={this.Login_data_username} placeholder="Username"/>
<label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" onChange={this.Login_data_password} placeholder="Password"/>
```

You have set the `username` and `password` words on input tag's id **2 times** and because of that, only latest ones in `Login.js` file will work.

Comment: Hi.I tried the above steps but i still get an error while submitting the registration form saying that cannot do post on register.js

Comment: Can you post the exact error statement? Maybe your code has another problem.

Comment: This is the exact error message.Cannot POST /registernow and this is the error returned in the console Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src http://localhost:3000”). Source: ;(function installGlobalHook(window) {
 ....

Comment: Can we move this conversation to chat?.But the login form works perfectly.And if i try to execute the function without the form tag,the function is not getting called.